# Birkhoff Lattice of a forest

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets, enumerative-combinatorics

In my research, I stumbled upon a particular kind of poset and I was wondering, whether there is something in the literature (I could not find anything so far).

They are distributive lattice $L$ such that their associated subposet of join-irreducibles is a forest (so $L$ is the Birkhoff lattice of a forest). Is there anything known in the literature about these lattices?

Thanks!

Richard

Comment: What does it mean for a subposet to be a forest?

Comment: Every element is covered by at most one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This set of lattices is the closure of the set {poset with one element} under two allowed operations: adding a top element or taking a Cartesian product. This implies that the Möbius numbers are in $\{-1,0,1\}$. Any similar property whose behavior under the two operations can be easily followed can also be described on the familly.

EDIT: I have met them at least twice in my own research, first in a work on operads (https://hal-univ-paris13.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00165245/document) and more recently in https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01339996.

Comment: *Any* finite distributive lattice has Möbius numbers in $\{-1,0,1\}$.